# How to join 2 rows from the tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table here with the follow columns: `ApplicantID`, `Name` and `Age`. I would like to know how to join the 2 rows of applicant together to be displayed on the same table(php). I am trying to retrieve it from database. Thanks!

```
--------------------------------------
Applicant ID       Name       Age
--------------------------------------
001                John       20
002                Nick       22
```

Below is what I want it to return

```
--------------------------------------
Name1       Age1     Name2    Age2
--------------------------------------
John         20      Nick     22
```

EDIT: The code from Amit work, but the data returned is:

---

```
Name1       Age1     Name2    Age2
--------------------------------------
John         20      Nick     22
--------------------------------------
Nick         22      Judy     25
```

How do I only return Nick once?

Comment: What is the sense of having two applicant name in one row, what if you have 10 rows of applicant what does it looks like so I can know the concept and purpose of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use self join by using following query:-

```
SELECT applicant1.name, 
       applicant1.age,
       applicant2.name, 
       applicant2.age 
FROM applicant as applicant1
JOIN applicant applicant2 
    on applicant1.applicant_id+1 = applicant2.applicant_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Hi Amit, I have tried your code, and I manage to return the data. However, when I have a third row, it becomes like this. Basically in the second row, the member Nick becomes Name1. May I know how do I return the first row only?
-----------------------------------------------
Name1       Age1     Name2    Age2
-----------------------------------------------
John         20            Nick     22
Nick          22           Judy    24

Comment: @Azvier You can use limit as well for restrict the data.

Comment: SELECT applicant1.name, 
       applicant1.age,
       applicant2.name, 
       applicant2.age 
FROM applicant as applicant1
JOIN applicant applicant2 
    on applicant1.applicant_id+1 = applicant2.applicant_id
LIMIT 1;

Comment: Thanks Amit. Do you know how to return only distinct names? The name Nick appears twice. Once on the first row, and the second time on the 2nd row

Answer (score 2):

if you're using php, it could be like this :

let's assume that we have an array which have same value as your table.

```
$arr = [ 
          ['Applicant ID' => 001, 'Name' => 'John', 'Age' => 20],
          ['Applicant ID' => 002, 'Name' => 'Nick', 'Age' => 22],
       ];

$res = [];

foreach($arr as $key => $values){
   $names = 'Name'.($key+1);
   $ages = 'Age'.($key+1);
   $res[$names] = $values['Name'];
   $res[$ages]  = $values['Age'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am doing it with data from a phpmyadmin, does it work as well?

Comment: I doubt about it since you don't have limitation of the values

Answer (score 1):

you could use a cross (self)  join filtering the rows

```
  select a.name as name1, a.age as age1, b.name as name2, b.age as age2
  from  table1 as a
  cross join table2 as b 
  where a.applicant_ID = '001'
  and b.applicant_ID ='002'
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.